# Extract some data from an array PHP while using cURL

Tags: php, arrays

I'm using cURL.
I got the result in an array named **resp** as you can see below. But I don't know how to save only the first 19 characters into another array like var1[0].
Right now I only print them. (are like resp[0]='a', resp[1]='b', resp[2]='c',... and I want the first 19 characters to be saved into one call like var1[0]='abc..'.

I also tried with implode and array_merge, but no success.

```
$curl = curl_init();
// Set some options - we are passing in a useragent too here
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_URL => $var
    //CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'Codular Sample cURL Request'
));
// Send the request & save response to $resp
$resp = curl_exec($curl);
echo($resp);
// Close request to clear up some resources
curl_close($curl);


for($i = 0; $i <=18; ++$i) 
{
    echo($resp[$i]);
}
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Assuming that a character is stored at each index of `$resp`, you could take the following action:

```
$nineteen = '';
for($i = 0; $i <=18; ++$i) {
    $nineteen .= $resp[$i];
}
$var = array($nineteen);
```

This code adds all 19 chars to a string and then adds them to the `$var` array. Simple + readable.

You can also do this with `slice()` and `implode()`. Both methodologies have [roughly the same performance](http://www.sitecrafting.com/blog/php-string-concat-vs-array/).

Comment: That will create an array with the 19 elements but he wants a variable with the 19 characters, and from doc: "If you use array_push() to add one element to the array it's better to use $array[] = because in that way there is no overhead of calling a function."

Comment: Hello guys.
This works like a charm!
but I have another question: how can I print the $var ?
Anyway, it works with echo($nineteen);

Many thanks!